# omniauth with authlogic issue with authentications method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, authlogic, omniauth

I've been following this tutorial: http://emumair.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/social-network-authentication-with-omniauth-and-authlogic/. I've walked through it all and I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `authentications' for #User<User:0x54cd8d8>
```

Its failing in the controller: app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:21:in `create':

```
user.authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
```

Do I need to add a relationship to the user model for authentications?

My user model currently looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_authentic

def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
self.email = omniauth['user_info']['email']

# Update user info fetching from social network
case omniauth['provider']
when 'facebook'
# fetch extra user info from facebook
when 'twitter'
# fetch extra user info from twitter
end
end
end
```

My authentication.rb file is:

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
validates :user_id, :uid, :provider, :presence => true
validates_uniqueness_of :uid, :scope => :provider
end
```

Comment: Is there a migration you need to run to create the authentication table?

Comment: Yep, I created the migration shown in the tutorial and ran it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
```

Also note that 
    omniauth['user_info']['email']
changed to
    omniauth['info']['email']